# Add "default" headers to all boto requests?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

Is it possible to set default headers for boto requests?  Basically I want to include a couple of headers in every API call I make to S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, extra headers have to be specified on each request.  The various methods of the bucket and key class all take an optional headers parameter and the contents of that dict gets merged into the request headers.

Being able to specify extra headers at the bucket level and then have those merged into all requests automatically  sounds like a great feature.  I'll add that to boto in the near future.